# Adding several parameters to canvas addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, undefined, addeventlistener

I have the following array in **Javascript**:

```
//the image xpto is in the position
    //  (x,y)        (x+width,y)
    //  (x,y+height) (x+width,y+height)
    var imageLocations = {
        album : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, "Photo Album", false],
        interest : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, "Interests", false],
        family : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, "People", false],
        places : [ 0, 0, 0, 0, "Places", false],
    };
```

Then i add this event listener:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click(imageLocations), false);
```

when i pass him the imageLocations in the onClick the imageLocations is already defined, but then when i use it in the following code i am getting **cannot read property '5' of undefined** :

```
//if the link has been clicked, go to link
    function on_click(e, imageLocations) {
        if (imageLocations[0]**[5]**) {
            window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations[0][4];
        }else if(imageLocations[1][5]){
            window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations[1][4];
        }else if(imageLocations[2][5]){
            window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations[2][4];
        }else if(imageLocations[3][5]){
            window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations[3][4];
        }
    }
```

in this function i cant access the [5]. Why is this? i know it might be a scope problem but how do i pass the parameter imageLocations to this function properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an Object that contains arrays. Not the same thing as a multidimensional array.

try accessing this object via the prop name.

```
imagelocations['album'][5]
```

The error is pretty clear - '5' is not undefined, the object you are trying to hit is.

Answer (score 1):

`imageLocations` is an object therefore you have to access with the right keys:

```
function on_click(e, imageLocations) {
    if (imageLocations['album'][5]) {
        window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations['album'][4];
    }else if(imageLocations['interest'][5]){
        window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations['interest'][4];
    }else if(imageLocations['family'][5]){
        window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations['family'][4];
    }else if(imageLocations['places'][5]){
        window.location = "photoalbum.jsp?book="+imageLocations['places'][4];
    }
}
```

You are also passing the result from the `on_click` function as the handler. (witch is undefined)

You should pass the function instead:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
```

Comment: follow the @Bosworth99 answer. `imageLocations` is an object, therefore `imageLocations[0]` will be undefined. You should use `imageLocations['album'][5]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `on_click` function to be able to see `imageLocations`, then one solution is to use a closure.  Define your `on_click` function in the same function where `var imageLocations` is declared.

```
function init() {
    var imageLocations = [...];

    var on_click = function(e) {
        ...
    };

    canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);
}
```

You could also declare `var imageLocations` outside (above) the `init` function.  `on_click` would still be able to see it.  Just don't change it before `on_click` runs!

---

An alternative is to create a new function that has `imageLocations` bound to it:

```
   canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click.bind(canvas,imageLocations), false);

...

function on_click(imageLocations, e) {   // Note the order is switched
    ...
}
```

I haven't tested that, but I believe something like that could work.  `bind` can do "partial application", where it accepts some parameters, and returns you a function which will accept the remaining parameters later.